# calling fgets did not work as expected

Tags: c, fgets

I was trying to manipulate strings,so I used *gets*. but when I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), i found that *gets is is dangerous and should not be used.* so I turn on fgets, but it seems like the program **escape** the fgets line??? any ideas how to solve it

## code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char message[200];
    int chx;
    puts("===[0]ENCODE===");
    puts("===[1]DECODE===");

   HERE: 
   printf("$>\t"); 
    scanf("%d", &chx);
   if(chx != (0) && chx != (1)) goto HERE;
    printf("ENTER YOUR MESSAGE TO %s IT:\t", chx == 0 ? "ENCODE":"DECODE");
    fgets(message, sizeof(message), stdin);
    printf("%s", message);
    return 0;
}
```

## execution

```
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:master$ ./a.out
===[0]ENCODE===
===[1]DECODE===
$>  1
ENTER YOUR MESSAGE TO DECODE IT:    
arubu@CQ56-LinuxMachine:master$
```

> gcc version 5.3.0 20151204 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04)

Comment: Why are you using `goto`? Why have you got `(0)` and `(1)`

Comment: `scanf("%d", &chx);` --> `scanf("%d", &chx);getchar();`//<<-eat newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the problem is salved, THANK YOU!